# Not being able to choose the right content of the right cell

Tags: objective-c, tableview, cell

I have black colored views on top of all cells created and when user taps on a certain cell, its alpha goes to 0.0f.

What I've been struggling with is that cells reuse identifier hence when I change something of a certain cell, some other cells contents also get edited because they share the same indexPath.

How do I access to one specific cell's content?

This is what I'm doing -

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *videoGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveVideoPlayer:)];
[self.optionView addGestureRecognizer:videoGesture];



-(void)moveVideoPlayer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {

     CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){.origin = self.tableView.contentOffset, .size = self.view.bounds.size};
     CGPoint visiblePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect));
     NSIndexPath *visibleIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:visiblePoint];

     self.visibleIndex = (int)visibleIndexPath.row;

     SearchCell *cell = (SearchCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:visibleIndexPath];
     NSLog(@"object ID : %@",cell.objectId);


     cell.greyView.alpha = 0.0f;

}
```

Comment: what need of UITapGesture?  table view didSelect method already there

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void) moveVideoPlayer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
  {
       CGPoint location = [tap locationInView:tableView];
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView  indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
       UITableViewCell *tapCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];

     //Your own code...
 }
```

Try this..

Comment: You mean like this? CGPoint location = [tap locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView  indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
        SearchCell *tapCell = (SearchCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: This is doing the same thing - all the other cells with the same indexPaths are being selected.

Comment: Can you please provide me your tap gesture implementation code.

Comment: From my experience in order to get a specific cell is to search it by its row number. I've done something like that long time ago but now it's forgotten.. I don't think I can ever make this work with just indexPath.

Comment: is your self.optionview is tableview object. If "Yes" use SearchCell *tapCell = (SearchCell)[self.optionview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: No it's not but that does not matter since it's tableview's subview, tapped coordinates are the same.

Comment: if your are provide it to subview then you have write guesture code in cellforrowatindexpath method with tag  or you can do it by using [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:videoGesture]; instead of [self.optionView addGestureRecognizer:videoGesture];

Comment: http://belencruz.com/2015/03/swipe-gestures-in-a-uitableview/  this is an example for swipe gesture in tableview instead of swipe gesture use tap gesture

Comment: Just followed the instructions from the article, same result. It's just a different method for the same thing...

Comment: so can you send me your code on goelajay602@gmail.com.

Comment: Just sent.. Thank you so much for helping me..!

Comment: Your github file's empty.